# Javascript Displaytemplate not working on sharepoint 2013 blog site view post page

Tags: javascript, view, blog, client-side-rendering

I have a blog site in sharepoint 2013, I wanted to use Javascript Template for displaying the Post in a custom style.
Here is how my js file looks like.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {'Body':{'View': CBody}};    
    alert("CSR Registered");    
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})(); 

function CBody(ctx) {
    var ret = ctx.CurrentItem.Body + "<b>" + 
    "<button onclick='alert("template working");'>Test Button</button>" + "</b>" ;
    return ret;
}
```

But When I use the file in JSLink of the Post Page (SiteCollection/sites/test/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=160)

I am unable to see the changes, the CSR is not getting registered and page is not displaying any errors.

In other Custom List I tried a similar approach, In the list I created a custom view and applied the JSLink template it worked fine however on the default AllItems View it failed to display the Custom template.

Can't we apply CSR on default views?. Help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLink file will work only if you use the JSLink url in the website like this.

```
~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/file.js
```

where the actual url of the file is

```
http://yourSPsite/sites/DevBlogs/_catalogs/masterpage/file.js
```

After this everything started working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the view supports JSLink it should work fine, for the default page too. You have an error within your CBody function. Below is the modified code:

```
 (function () {
   var overrideCtx = {};
   overrideCtx.Templates = {};
   overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {'Body':{'View': CBody}};
   window.console && console.log("CSR Registered"); //Removed alert, see your console F12
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
 })();

 function CBody(ctx) {
    var ret = ctx.CurrentItem.Body + "<b>" +
    "<button onclick=\"alert('template working');\">Test Button</button>" + "</b>" ;
    return ret;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried the above code also, it's not working for me. Similarly I have a CSR for a custom list, same JSLink file is being referred by the Default All Items view and a custom view. Custom view is able to display the custom CSR, whereas Default view is not. Do I need to turn on some feature, or turn off MDS anything I need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the help provided, as I examined in the F12 I couldn't find JSLink file and it's contents. How do I know it supports JSLink.